# How to improve the selection and drawing of this rectangle?

Tags: .net, vb.net, image

I need to show a region selector on my application to select a rectangle region over the screen.

I've taken and tried to modify to my needs [this code example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5dc1b32b-7b7e-41fe-af87-d491d7021bd3/vbnet-smooth-rectangle-drawing-using-mousedrag) of **Hans Passant**, the code selects an area with the mouse and draw a rectangle, it works only on a form and not on the screen ...but that is a problem for later 'cause first what I need is improve the functionality of this selector.

At the moment the rectangle selection can be done only starting from top-left to right-bottom, I need a more flexible selection to draw in all directions in one step (I mean a rectangle that can be able to select to right, left, bottom, up, etc)

A real example of the selection flexibility that I need is basically like the **Windows Explorer** selector does:

[image]

What more changes I should do in my code?:

PS: **I also accept a cleaver way to mimic the Windows selection rectangle flexibility (maybe using the WinAPI?).**

```
Public Class Form1

Dim SelectionRectangle As Rectangle

Private Shadows Sub Load() Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.DoubleBuffered = True
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    SelectionRectangle = New Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0)
    Me.Invalidate()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseUp(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)

    If SelectionRectangle.Width > 0 AndAlso SelectionRectangle.Height > 0 Then

        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        sb.AppendFormat("Selection Location: {0}", SelectionRectangle.Location.ToString)
        sb.AppendLine()
        sb.AppendFormat("Selection Size: {0}", SelectionRectangle.Size.ToString)
        MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString)

    End If

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)

    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left _
    AndAlso (SelectionRectangle.Right >= SelectionRectangle.X) _
    AndAlso (SelectionRectangle.Bottom >= SelectionRectangle.Y) Then

        SelectionRectangle = New Rectangle(SelectionRectangle.Left,
                                           SelectionRectangle.Top,
                                           e.X - SelectionRectangle.Left,
                                           e.Y - SelectionRectangle.Top)
        Me.Invalidate()

    Else
        SelectionRectangle = New Rectangle(SelectionRectangle.X,
                                           SelectionRectangle.Y,
                                           0, 0)
    End If

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)

    Using pen As New Pen(Color.Red, 1)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, SelectionRectangle)
    End Using

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Store the initial click point (X1,Y1), and based on the difference of the current mouse position (X2,Y2), you can determine the coordinates of the rectangle. For instance, if the mouse position is to the bottom right of the initial point, your rectangle would be (X1,Y1,X2,Y2). If it's to the top left of the initial point, your rectangle would be (X2,Y2,X1,Y1), and if it's to the bottom left, it would be (X2,Y1,X1,Y2), and so on.

Comment: @Digital_Utopia I've expected an help with a little code example, but anyways thankyou with your explanations and 10 minutes of playing with sums and rests I've solved it, feel free to post your comment in an answer to mark it as the accepted one, thanks.

Comment: Feel free to mark your own as an answer. I'm not familiar with VB.NET, otherwise I would've posted some code in an answer. I just hoped the basic logic would get you on the right track, and it looks like it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution according to **@Digital_Utopia** comment:

This way works with the same flexibility as the windows explorer selector, except that the rectangle is not filled with a color and the rectangle is not 'released' after 'mouse up' 'cause that is not what I need.

```
Dim SelectionRectangle As Rectangle
Dim InitialPosition As Point

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    ' Store the starting coordinates
    InitialPosition = e.Location
    SelectionRectangle = New Rectangle(InitialPosition.X, InitialPosition.Y, 0, 0)
    Me.Invalidate()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)

    ' Me.SuspendLayout()

    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then

        If (e.Location.X < InitialPosition.X) _
        AndAlso (e.Location.Y < InitialPosition.Y) Then ' Top-Left

            SelectionRectangle = New Rectangle(e.X,
                                               e.Y,
                                               InitialPosition.X - e.X,
                                               InitialPosition.Y - e.Y)

        ElseIf (e.Location.X > InitialPosition.X) _
        AndAlso (e.Location.Y < InitialPosition.Y) Then ' Top-Right

            SelectionRectangle = New Rectangle(InitialPosition.X,
                                               e.Y,
                                               e.X - InitialPosition.X,
                                               InitialPosition.Y - e.Y)

        ElseIf (e.Location.X < InitialPosition.X) _
        AndAlso (e.Location.Y > InitialPosition.Y) Then ' Bottom-Left

            SelectionRectangle = New Rectangle(e.X,
                                               InitialPosition.Y,
                                               InitialPosition.X - e.X,
                                               e.Y - InitialPosition.Y)

        ElseIf (e.Location.X > InitialPosition.X) _
        AndAlso (e.Location.Y > InitialPosition.Y) Then ' Bottom-Right

            SelectionRectangle = New Rectangle(InitialPosition.X,
                                               InitialPosition.Y,
                                               e.X - InitialPosition.X,
                                               e.Y - InitialPosition.Y)
        End If

        Me.Invalidate()

    End If

    ' Me.ResumeLayout()

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)

    Using pen As New Pen(Color.Red, 1)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, SelectionRectangle)
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: add `FillRectangle` to the OnPaint for the collor fill thing;  then onMouseup, add `SelectionRectangle = Rectangle.Empty` to OnMouseUp to release it (or add a IsSelecting boolean); then you'll need some `If isSelecting` or test SelectedRect = empty to test when to draw it/fill it.  very similar to a Drag Drop

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can find something usefull inside of the source of the GreenShot application!?
http://sourceforge.net/projects/greenshot/

Because the use a rectangle trap to select the area for the Screenshot you need!

Comment: Thanks for answer but how that could help me? there is no (or I can't find) the source of the project.

Comment: Maybe here!? I have no time to go through all the code but i think it should be inside. [link](https://bitbucket.org/greenshot/greenshot/src/01ce82dbebf5906d745d0a83de416681facad131/Greenshot/Helpers/CaptureHelper.cs?at=1.1) If the link does not work try to follow Code > Source > GreenShot > helpers > Capture helper! I hope this helps you!

Comment: thanks, it really seems interesting and I could learn something new for the future in the source code, but it's hard C# and should be  a nightmare to translate by myself to VB.NET, anyways thankyou so much

Comment: You are right its not a nice job to convert the code by hand! I use this side in some cases! http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/