# Position mouse with RotateTransformed DrawString

Tags: vb.net, graphics, mouseevent, gdi+

I want to rotate text in a display. I'm trying to position the string by dragging a rectangle to illustrate the area for the DrawString method.

I'm using RotateTransform and TranslateTransform, which works fine.  However, when dragging, the mouse cursor doesn't get transformed to stay at the bottom corner of the rectangle being dragged.

What am I missing...? ;-)

Here is some example code, which draws onto the base Windows Form, and can be pasted straight into a Windows Form

```
Public Class Form1
Dim drawingShape As Boolean = False
Dim mDown, mPos As Point
Dim bitMap1 As Bitmap
Dim txt As String = "Hello folks, here is some text"
Dim angle As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    bitMap1 = New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    If drawingShape Then
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(angle, Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append)
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(mDown.X, mDown.Y, Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append)
        Dim rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, mPos.X - mDown.X, mPos.Y - mDown.Y)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rect)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txt, New Font("Calibri", 12), Brushes.Green, rect)
        e.Graphics.ResetTransform()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown
    mDown = e.Location
    drawingShape = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
    mPos = e.Location
    Me.Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseUp
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap1)
    g.RotateTransform(angle, Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append)
    g.TranslateTransform(mDown.X, mDown.Y, Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append)
    Dim rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, mPos.X - mDown.X, mPos.Y - mDown.Y)
    g.DrawString(txt, New Font("Calibri", 12), Brushes.Blue, rect)
    'g.ResetTransform()
    g.Dispose()
    Me.BackgroundImage = bitMap1
    drawingShape = False
    angle += 45
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: `xxxTransform` transforms the related Graphics object not the aspect of the entire app. You need to manually convert the mouse location.  For example when angle=90, then MDown==Rect Left, so only make it taller when they move left. It might be easier (less code) to collect the rectangle in normal perspective (angle=0) then transform only the finished product; maybe using a temp bmp until the user says OK.  The text might also look better using TextRender rather than DrawString.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23623490/1070452) is an example of what I am talking about for just a basic rect

Answer (score 0):

You could use ‘Cursor.X`and ‘Cursor.Y` to position the mouse where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input. I eventually have it working, updated code is below. I used the vector routines from System.Windows.Vector and matrices from System.Windows.Media.Matrix.  These provide matrix multiply functionality. Not sure if this is considered good practice, because classes such as Point clash with System.Drawing classes.

Note:  These vector classes require the program to reference WindowsBase

The program works by creating a vector describing the drag movement since the mouse button was clicked. Because this vector is created whilst the text display box is being dragged - i.e. the box has been rotated to display it - the vector is converted back to what it would be if it was drawing a normal horizontal rectangle.  This horizontal rectangle ("normalised rectangle") is what is then rotated to achieve the currently-dragged text display box.

The code only requires a basic form to run

```
Public Class Form1
Dim drawingShape As Boolean = False                 ' True during mouse-drag
Dim mDown, mPos As Point                            ' Mouse-Button-Down, and current mouse position
Dim bitMap1 As Bitmap                               ' Background display to hold drawn items
Dim txt As String = "Hello folks, here is some text"
Dim angle As Integer = 0                            ' Angle to rotate text through (0 = along X-axis)
Dim rect As Rectangle                               ' Rectangle holding text - which is then transformed
Dim vecRectDiag As New Windows.Vector               ' Vector TopLeft-BotRight of rect holding text
Dim mxIdentWin As System.Windows.Media.Matrix       ' Identity matrix for resetting before rotating
Dim mxNegAngle As System.Windows.Media.Matrix       ' Matrix to transform mouse cursor vector back to horizontal
Dim botRight As Point                               ' Bottom-right corner of rect rectangle
Dim mVecWin As New Windows.Vector                   ' Vector showing mouse movement since mouse-button-down
Dim pen1red, pen2yel, pen3turq, pen4lime, pen5corn As Pen

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    bitMap1 = New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)
    mxIdentWin = New Windows.Media.Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)         ' Identity matrix
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    If drawingShape Then
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-mDown.X, -mDown.Y, Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append)
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(angle, Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append)
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(mDown.X, mDown.Y, Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rect)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txt, New Font("Calibri", 12), Brushes.Green, rect)
        e.Graphics.ResetTransform()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown
    mDown = e.Location                  ' Location of mouse button click
    drawingShape = True
    mxNegAngle = mxIdentWin             ' Reset the negative-rotate matrix...
    mxNegAngle.Rotate(-angle)           ' ... and re-rotate with the new angle
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
    mPos = e.Location
    mVecWin = New Windows.Vector(mPos.X - mDown.X, mPos.Y - mDown.Y)        ' Vector showing the real mouse movement
    vecRectDiag = Windows.Vector.Multiply(mVecWin, mxNegAngle)              ' Vector to the normalised horizontal rectangle - which now needs transforming
    botRight = New Point(CInt(mDown.X + vecRectDiag.X), CInt(mDown.Y + vecRectDiag.Y))      ' Bottom right of normalised horizontal rectangle
    rect = New Rectangle(mDown.X, mDown.Y, botRight.X - mDown.X, botRight.Y - mDown.Y)
    If drawingShape Then Me.Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseUp
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap1)
    g.TranslateTransform(-mDown.X, -mDown.Y, Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append)
    g.RotateTransform(angle, Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append)
    g.TranslateTransform(mDown.X, mDown.Y, Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append)
    g.DrawString(txt, New Font("Calibri", 12), Brushes.Blue, rect)
    g.ResetTransform()
    g.Dispose()
    Me.BackgroundImage = bitMap1
    drawingShape = False
    angle += 45
End Sub

End Class
```